# Python TypeError: Cannot do slice stop value indexing on <class 'pandas.core.index.Int64Index'>

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

Am getting a Type Error, while trying to filter some past data using python and pandas. Here's the error

> TypeError: cannot do slice stop value indexing on < class
>   'pandas.core.index.Int64Index'> with these indexers [327.0] of < type
>   'float'>

**Code**

```
# 65% of training data
ratio = 0.65
train_data_df = df_replace[:round(dataset_length*ratio)]  
test_data_df = df_replace[-(1-round(dataset_length*ratio)):]  

# Create Respected CSV
train_data_df.to_csv('Train.csv',index=False)
test_data_df.to_csv('Test.csv',index=False)
```

**Additional Info**

The code is working upto creating a new CSV file `India_in_Tests_Filter.csv` that has more than 450 rows and 3 columns as follows:

```
Result Toss Bat

Lost   won  1st 
Won    won  2nd
```

While `India_in_Tests.csv` have more than 450 rows and 7 columns.

So folks, any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(range(10), list(range(320, 330)))
```

then slice it with

```
df[:327.0]
```

> ```
> TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'>
> with these indexers [327.0] of <type 'float'>
> ```

your `round` function is returning a `float`.  Make it an `int` instead

```
df[:int(327.0)]
```

### [image]

***what your code should look like***

```
train_data_df = df_replace[:int(dataset_length*ratio)]  
test_data_df = df_replace[-(1-int(dataset_length*ratio)):]
```

Comment: Oh damn, I tried everything else except this. Thanks, now its just working fine in python 2.7 as well. Cheers!